# Merge two bytes to int

Tags: java, android

I have two bytes, `byte b1`, `byte b2`.

`b1` decimal value is 44.

`b2` decimal value is 1.

I would like to join the bytes together (but not sum), to create a number like 441.

How do I achieve that?

Comment: What if the byte values are in range `0x80` to `0xFF`, i.e. negative byte values?

Comment: All the bytes I use has only positive values.

Comment: So they are all in range 0 - 127?

Comment: Yes, exactly like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Mathematical approach**

```
double digitCount = Math.floor(Math.log10(b2) + 1.0);
int result = b1 * (int) Math.pow(10, digitCount) + b2;
```

---

**Iterative approach** (slice one digit at a time from right to left)

```
int result = 0;
int digit, multiplier = 1;
int base = b2;
while (base > 0) {
    digit = base % 10;
    base /= 10;
    result += digit * multiplier;
    multiplier *= 10;
}

base = b1;
while (base > 0) {
    digit = base % 10;
    base /= 10;
    result += digit * multiplier;
    multiplier *= 10;
}
```

---

**Straightforward approach** (concatenate as strings and parse)

```
int result = Integer.parseInt("" + b1 + b2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could convert them to strings, then concatenate the strings, and then parse it to an int:

```
Integer.parseInt(Byte.toString(b1) + Byte.toString(b2))
```

Comment: Boxing the `byte` just to call `toString()` is overkill. Use `Byte.toString(b1)` instead.

Comment: Lol @Andreas Byte.toString? Lol you could just concatenate the byte to string and you get the same result with less characters used.

Comment: @JianAstrero Don't tell me, tell Gábor Gévay, who wanted to use `toString`. I'm just pointing out that there is a better `toString` for this. Whether `""+b1+b2` is better than `Byte.toString(b1) + Byte.toString(b2)` is a matter of opinion. I personally hate the `"" +` construct for triggering string concatenation.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas, I edited the answer to use the static `toString` of Byte.
And I agree that whether the `"" +` method is preferable is a matter of taste; that's why I added my answer, even though the one using `"" +` was already there.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin:

```
val b1: Byte = 44.toByte()
val b2: Byte = 1.toByte()
print("$b1$b2")
```

Java

```
byte b1 = (byte)44;
byte b2 = (byte)1;
System.out.print(b1+""+b2);
```

Comment: If you hadn't made `44` a `long` literal, you wouldn't have needed to cast to `byte`.

Comment: That was just a mistake when i pressed semi colon.

Comment: And hence the two `(byte)` casts are redundant, and can be removed.

Comment: So making a String and reading a number from it would be the best solution?

Comment: Yes, it is the best solution. You have control on what the string is so you wont have problems on converting it to an integer.